How to address export set problems in third party cmake library?
In my C++ project I want to link against clang libc++ instead of libstdc++ on Ubuntu.
I build libc++ as part of my CMake projects via add_subdirectory so I can build it with different debug and sanitizer configurations.
My CMakeLists.txt looks as following:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(sample C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


# clang libc++
set(LLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES "libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(external/llvm-project/runtimes EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL SYSTEM)
link_libraries(
    cxx_shared
    cxxabi_shared
)

# Google Benchmark
set(BENCHMARK_ENABLE_TESTING OFF)
set(BENCHMARK_ENABLE_INSTALL OFF)
add_subdirectory(external/benchmark EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL SYSTEM)

# executable
add_executable(sample src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sample PUBLIC benchmark::benchmark)

Both repositories (llvm-project and benchmark) are cloned from github in the external directory.
I am using link_libraries to make libc++ a dependency of every target definition that follows so it is not just linked to my main executable but also all dependencies.
This works great for all of my 20 dependencies except for google benchmark where I get the following error:
CMake Error in external/benchmark/src/CMakeLists.txt:
  export called with target "benchmark" which requires target "cxx_shared"
  that is not in any export set.

CMake Error in external/benchmark/src/CMakeLists.txt:
  export called with target "benchmark" which requires target "cxxabi_shared"
  that is not in any export set.

This is caused by an unconditional export statement in benchmark/src/CMakeLists.txt:
export (
  TARGETS ${targets_to_export}
  NAMESPACE "${namespace}"
  FILE ${generated_dir}/${targets_export_name}.cmake
)

if (BENCHMARK_ENABLE_INSTALL)
...
endif()

For now I have forked the google benchmark repo and remove the export, however I would like to move away from that and am wondering what to do:

Is there a way to tell cmake that I don't care about any export sets in my project? For installs there is CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY but I couldn't find anything for exports.

Shall I report this to google benchmark and ask them to make the export conditionally. Before it was part of BENCHMARK_ENABLE_INSTALL, but they moved it outside in this commit. Is it reasonable to ask them to introduce another variable? My other dependencies that use export statements (fmt, GSL, boost, abseil ..) all make them part of the install-if-clauses, or don't have them.

Shall I report this to llvm-project and ask them to define export sets. I never worked with export so I don't know if that is reasonable to ask a project to provide it.

Can I define the export set myself for the libcxx targets? I tried a naïve export(TARGET cxx_shared ...) and ran into all kinds of problems issues, like paths that are set absolute, and much more.



Remove all lines between # clang libc++ and # Google Benchmark and use normal compiler options -stdlib=libc++ in CXX_FLAGS or CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or target compiler flags.

LLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES is for building LLVM. I don't think you build it.

@273K: Given project actually builds the sub-project with llvm runtimes: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/runtimes. cxx_shared and cxxabi_shared are targets created in that sub-project.

"I tried a naïve export(TARGET cxx_shared ...) and ran into all kinds of problems issues, like paths that are set absolute, and much more." - Absolute paths are not an issue in the export file. This file describes the build tree, which cannot be (not intended to be) used on other machines and cannot be moved into other location.

Based on @Tsyvarev comment I played a bit more with the export command and found the following working:
export(TARGETS 
    cxx_shared cxxabi_shared cxx-headers cxxabi_shared_objects 
    libcxx-abi-headers cxxabi-headers 
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/llvm_runtime.cmake"
)

Adding the above makes everything work.
I am still not sure if it is the best idea to add this to the cmake config. And wonder if there is another way.
